# SQL generate score column from multi-condition test on a notes cell

Tags: sql, select, multiple-conditions

Basically I have a table with a notes column and I want to generate a column that looks for a few conditions and spits out a score based on how many conditions were met when looking at each note. I may be going about this the wrong way so please feel free to tangent.

Query so far:

```
SELECT
SUM(
    SUM(case when notes like '%Tuna%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    SUM(case when notes like '%apple%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    SUM(case when notes like '%burrito' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            --      ) as score
,Name
,Date
,Notes
FROM food_jrnl
```

Example table food_jrnl:

```
Name    Date    Note
Peter   6/1/2016    Just mountain Dew and cheatos
Jimmy   5/25/2016   Chocolate cake, cheesy potatoes and ketchup
Sophie  5/16/2016   just grits and tuna!!
Bianca  5/9/2016    Chocolate milk, Ahi tuna, Gala apple
Sam 4/23/2016   Tuna salad
Josh    1/10/2016   Had a banana and apple with orange juice
```

What I am hoping to create:

```
Score   Name    Date    Note
0   Peter   6/1/2016    Just mountain Dew and cheatos
0   Jimmy   5/25/2016   Chocolate cake, cheesy potatoes and ketchup
1   Sophie  5/16/2016   just grits and tuna!!
2   Bianca  5/9/2016    Chocolate milk, Ahi tuna, Gala apple
1   Sam 4/23/2016   Tuna salad
0   Josh    1/10/2016   Had a banana and apple with orange juice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use `sum` for this:

```
SELECT
    case when notes like '%Tuna%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    case when notes like '%apple%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    case when notes like '%burrito' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as score
    ,Name
    ,Date
    ,Notes
FROM food_jrnl
```

Comment: I did not realize using multiple sums could be added together but that makes sense when i see it. Also did not know it required a group by for all columns! you are the best! - I must have posted after you changed you answer. The Case when is much leaner, does not need the group by! Thanks!